# How to pass 2-D array in postgress from python?

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array

**I am trying to insert 2-d numeric array in Postgres as below:**

```sql
INSERT INTO student (studentScore) VALUES ('{ {"1", "21.0"},   {"2", "22.0"}, {"3", "46.0"} }')
```

*"studentScore"* column mentioned below is of type ***numeric[][]***

**Ex**: studentScore is an array of {subjectId, studentMarks}.
So, it contains {"1", "21.0"} for subjectId "1", {"2", "22.0"} for subjectId2, etc....

The above query works fine via Postgres terminal but I would like to know how to pass it through python code.

I am able to insert data in 1-d array format as below.

```py
"studentScore":    '{ "21.0","22.0" }'
```

but I am not able to figure out the exact syntax for setting 2-d array from python, which should be somewhat like this :

```py
 "studentScore":  '{ ["1", "21.0"] , ["2", "22.0"] }'
```

Probably, I need to create a loop & assign the values for {subjectId, studentMarks} in above column.

Can anyone please suggest with syntax

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said which driver you're using. [psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/) seems to be the most common, so we'll go with that.

Your original syntax will work to insert a new record into PostgreSQL using a tool like pgAdmin or other:

```
INSERT INTO student (studentScore) 
VALUES ('{ {"1", "21.0"},   {"2", "22.0"}, {"3", "46.0"} }')
```

But you can also use this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO student (studentScore) 
VALUES ('{ {1, 21.0}, {2, 22.0}, {3, 46.0} }')
```

This second syntax you can use in Python:

```
import psycopg2
import sys

conn = psycopg2.connect('<connection string>')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("""
               INSERT INTO student (studentScore)
                    VALUES ('{ {44, 21.0}, {2, 22.0}, {3, 46.0} }');
               COMMIT;
               """)
```

I'm using triple double quotes for multiline strings. But you could also use plain double quotes:

```
cur.execute(" INSERT INTO student (studentScore) VALUES ('{{44, 21.0}, {2, 22.0}, {3, 46.0} }'); COMMIT;")
```

You can also make your own nested list and pass that to psycopg2 using query placeholders:

```
scoreList2D = [[1,21.0], [2,22.0], [3,46.0]]
cur.execute('INSERT INTO student (studentscore) VALUES(%s); COMMIT;',
       (scoreList2D,))
```

For dynamic values where you have separate lists studentIds and studentMarks, you'll need a loop to populate a nested (2D) list:

```
studentIds = [1, 2, 3]
studentMarks = [21.0, 22.0, 46]
studentScore = []
for i, item in enumerate(studentIds):
    studentScore.append([studentIds[i], studentMarks[i])

cur.execute('INSERT INTO student (studentscore) VALUES(%s); COMMIT;',
       (scoreList2D,))
```

This code only works properly if there is a rigid 1:1 ratio between studentIds and studentMarks.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to pass static values as   :              
"studentScore": '{ {1, 21.0 }, {2, 22.0}, {3, 46} }' 

Now, I would like to populate dynamic values in above format using two lists. 
First list containing subjectIds & second containing studentMarks.        

So, we need to populate in below format :            
'{   {subject1, marks1 }, {subject2, marks2 }, {subject3, marks3 } , ..............}'

Please share python syntax for it.

Comment: @TanujKathuria, see my edit.